# Problema al ejecutar Expo desde la consola

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-native

Tengo un problema acabo de instalar Expo Devs Tools mediante la consola de windows pero al ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error :

> [00:31:17] Can't read JSON file: C:\Users\ACTIVA DIGITAL\package.json
>   [00:31:17] └─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ACTIVA DIGITAL\package.json'
>   [00:31:17] No Expo configuration found. Are you sure this is a project directory?

Los 2 primeros errores los marca en rojo 
El tercero en amarillo.

Comment: mmm, bueno, lo que dice el error, no encuentra el archivo `package.json` y que si estás seguro si estás en el directorio del proyecto. Si no pones más detalles de lo que has hecho o lo que quieres, no es mucha más la ayuda que puedas recibir. Saludos

Comment: Lo instale mediante la consola, pero no me ejecuta. Dicho archivo no esta en el directorio especifico. ¿Cual podria ser la solución?